# Como eu continuo a repetição enquanto não for digitado nenhuma das condições S/N?

Tags: java

Preciso que se nenhuma das condições 'S','s','N','n' for digitada pelo usuário o programa continue perguntando "Deseja continuar a execução?(S/N):"

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

    Double precobruto,desconto,precoavista; 
    int numex;
    char opcao;

    System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de produtos:");
    numex = sc.nextInt();

    for(int i=0; i<=numex; i++){
    System.out.println("Insira o valor do produto:");   
    precobruto = sc.nextDouble();

    desconto = (precobruto*0.1);

    precoavista = precobruto - desconto;

    System.out.println("Preço bruto: "+formatador.format(precobruto));
    System.out.println("Preço a vista: "+formatador.format(precoavista));
    System.out.println("Desconto (10%): "+formatador.format(desconto));
    System.out.print("\n");
    System.out.println("Deseja continuar a execução?(S/N):");
    opcao = sc.next().charAt(0);

    if (opcao == 'n' || opcao == 'N'){
    System.exit(0);
}
    if (opcao == 's' || opcao == 'S'){
    continue;
}
    else{
    System.out.println("Deseja continuar a execução?(S/N):");
}
        }
    }
```

Comment: `do... while` é a solucao

Comment: Da pra otimizar esse codigo, mas pra isso, vc precisa explicar o que pretende com esse codigo primeiro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basta usar do..while:

```
do {

//o codigo a ser repetido caso a condição nao atenda

while(opcao != 'n' || opcao != 'N');
```

Dessa forma, não é necessário validar S ou s pois o while ficará em loop até que o usuário informe as chars indicadas.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o laço de repetição `do while`.
O `do while` executa uma função primeiro e verifica até que a condição seja falsa 
para parar a execução.

Dê uma olhada aqui para entender mais afundo https://www.devmedia.com.br/while-e-do-while-lacos-de-repeticoes-estrutura-da-linguagem-parte-1/18870

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

DecimalFormat formatador = new DecimalFormat("0.00");

Double precobruto,desconto,precoavista; 
int numex;
char opcao;

do {

System.out.print("Informe a quantidade de produtos:");
numex = sc.nextInt();

for(int i=0; i<=numex; i++){
System.out.println("Insira o valor do produto:");   
precobruto = sc.nextDouble();

desconto = (precobruto*0.1);

precoavista = precobruto - desconto;

System.out.println("Preço bruto: "+formatador.format(precobruto));
System.out.println("Preço a vista: "+formatador.format(precoavista));
System.out.println("Desconto (10%): "+formatador.format(desconto));
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.println("Deseja continuar a execução?(S/N):");
opcao = sc.next().charAt(0);

if (opcao == 'n' || opcao == 'N'){
System.exit(0);

} while (opcao != 'n' || opcao != 'N')
```

Comment: Eu adicionei   while(opcao != 'n' || opcao != 'N'){
  System.out.println("Deseja continuar a execução?(S/N):");
  opcao = sc.next().charAt(0);
   } porém ele não responde à 'S', 'N'

Comment: @GustavoLopes pode responder ao que perguntei abaixo da sua pergunta? Esse codigo seu pode ser melhorado, tem mt coisa desnecessaria nele, dependendo do objetivo